# how to skip a few iterations in a loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have the C code below

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("Hello");
    if(i == 5){
        a[3] = a[2] * 2;
        if(a[3] == b)
            i = a[3];           //Skip to index = a[3]; depends on runtime value
    }
}
```

How to convert to Ruby? I know we can skip one iteration using `next`, but I have to skip a few iterations depending on conditional value and I don't know how many iterations to skip before runtime?

---

Here is the code I am actually working on (as mentioned by Coreyward):

I am looking for "straight line" in the array that the values differs less than 0.1(less than 0.1 will considered as a "straight line"). The range has to be longer than 50 to be considered as a long "line". After I find the line range [a,b], i wanna skip the iterations to upper limit b so it would not start again from a+1, and it will start to find new "straight line" from b+1

```
for(i=0; i<arr.Length; i++){
  if(arr[i] - arr[i + 50] < 0.1){
    m = i;                                   //m is the starting point
    for(j=i; j<arr.Length; j++){             //this loop makes sure all values differs less than 0.1
      if(arr[i] - arr[j] < 0.1){
        n = j;
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
    if(n - m > 50){                          //Found a line with range greater than 50, and store the starting point to line array
      line[i] = m
    }
    i = n                                     //Start new search from n
  }
```

}

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you provided the intent of what you're trying to accomplish. There are some pretty handy methods in the Enumerator class that let you set the value for the next iteration (`feed`) and see the next value (`peek`), and you're also able to use a `for` loop in Ruby. I'm sure there's a cleaner way of writing this, I just don't know what it's trying to do.

Comment: You're going to index off the end of your array in C, probably want to change the bound to `arr.Length-50`. This seems like a somewhat convoluted way to find runs of 50 or more whose values are with epsilon of the initial value.

Comment: You seem to be assuming values at larger index are never less than values at lower index. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using the [enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) class:

```
iter = (1..10).to_enum
while true
  value = iter.next
  puts "value is #{value.inspect}"
  if value == 5
    3.times {value = iter.next}
  end
end
```

gives

```
value is 1
value is 2
value is 3
value is 4
value is 5
value is 9
value is 10
StopIteration: iteration reached at end
        from (irb):15:in `next'
        from (irb):15
        from C:/Ruby19/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This is cute, but not an equivalence to advancing an index directly. If one is iterating through an array with i and reaches a decision where one wants to advance to index j, doing `(j-i).times{iter.next}` is more complex and expensive than just assigning `i = j`

Answer (score 3):

Your case isn't easily covered by typical ruby iterators, but ruby also has ordinary while loops which can completely cover c-for. the following is equivalent to your c for loop above.

```
i = 0;
while i < 10 
  puts "Hello"
  if i == 5
    a[3] = a[2] * 2
    i = a[3] if a[3] == b
  end
  # in your code above, the for increment i++ will execute after assigning new i,
  # though the comment "Skip to index = a[3]" indicates that may not be your intent
  i += 1  
end
```

Comment: Yes this works, but is there any way to do it with Enumerators? I was thinking about `drop` so it will drop the values between 5 and a[3], but was confused and lost when I start coding.