# How to jump n iterations of the current loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`next` jumps to the next iteration, but I need some way to jump *n* iterations. For example, if I call a fictitious `next(2)` it jumps two iterations. Can this be done?

My project is written in Rails but this is a Ruby problem -- here's something that represents my project:

```
answer_set_one.each |answer_one| 
  answer_set_two.each |answer_two|
    #in here, if answer_two and answer_one matches, do something
  end
end
```

However, once `answer_two` has matched with any `answer_one`, it cannot match with any other `answer_one`.

Comment: I think you need to skip using `next` till you want the loop to continue or use an increamenter and set the value to `n`, but then you need to iterate over the array using for or while loop.

Comment: It that approach works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930851/how-to-skip-a-few-iterations-in-a-loop-in-ruby

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Can you add an example? Having an example might help to come up with a good solution. For example in some case `step` might solve your problem.

Comment: I added an example!

Comment: ... seems like its a break instead of a next?

Comment: it cannot be a break because that terminates the loop entirely. I need the inner loop to keep running.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing inside the loop? Is the last sentence your problem or what you want to achieve?

Comment: @nachime Your intention is not clear to me. Could you provide an example with concrete data, please?

Comment: It doesnt break out of the entire loop.

Comment: I never said it did, I said " I need the inner loop to keep running. "

Comment: How do you need the inner loop if it won't match any more elements?

Comment: @nachime I think I finally got what you mean heh. Will modify my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It should use a break instead. In response to your comment above, the break statement does not exit both the loops. Try this one out to be clear:

```
[1,2,3].each do |x|
  p x
  %w(a b).each do |y|
    p y
    break if y == 'a'
  end
end;
```

EDIT: After the further clarification, this should do what you want?

```
answer_set_one.each |answer_one| 
  matched = false
  answer_set_two.each |answer_two|
    next if matched
    matched = true if answer_two == answer_one
    # do whatever you still need to do here
  end
end
```

Comment: In the edited version, the loop just keeps wasting cpu cycles needlessly. It won't do any more work. Why not just break from the inner loop, when we find a match? Granted, it was an explicit requirement from an OP, but given the current detail of information provided, it's a silly requirement.

Comment: There could be additional requirements, or other things to be done after its matched. For example, perhaps he wants to execute command A to all answer_twos and only B to the matched ones. In that case, command A just needs to come before the next.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write your loop here?

For example, in this loop

```
(1..10).each do |a|
 next if a.even?
 puts a
end
```

it prints out 1,3,5,7,9 so essentially it jumps 2 iterations

You could use a `next if` statement if that fits your loop

Answer (score 0):

Why not using shift ? As follows (to skip 3 elements):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
skip = 3

arr.each do |x|
  p x
  (skip-1).times {arr.shift}
end

$ ruby test.rb
1
4
7
10
```

Answer (score 0):

following to your code, look into this:

```
answer_set_one = (1..9).to_a
answer_set_two = (1..9).to_a

answer_set_one.each do |answer_one| 
  answer_set_two.each do |answer_two|
    #in here, if answer_two and answer_one matches, do something
    puts answer_one
    break if answer_two == answer_one
  end
end
```

when it find that `answer_one == answer_two` it stops looking for another answer.